# Unable to perform calculations on values ajax,javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to perform calculations on #totalFish,#totalDiesel when I add arithmetic operators id does not give any result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txtdiesel,#txtfish').keyup(function() {
    var price3 = $('#exp').text();

    var qty3 = $('#totalDiesel').text();
    var fish = $('#totalFish').text();
    var cal = price3 + qty3;
    var total = fish - cal;

    $('#ramount').html(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td style="font-size:14px" id="display">
</td>

<td>
  <div style="font-size:medium;" id="totalFish" class="totalFish">Rs.</td>
<td>
  <div style="font-size:medium;" id="totalDiesel" class="totalDiesel">Rs.</td>
<td>
  <div style="font-size:medium;" id="ramount" class="ramount">Rs.</div>
</td>



<td><input id="txtfish" placeholder="Multiply Fish Weight" type="number" name="txtfish" /></td> 
<td><input id="txtdiesel" placeholder="Multiply diesel" type="number" name="txtdiesel" /></td>
```

Comment: We are missing some of your html like `txtdiesel` and others. Also note that `.text()` returns a string. you need to convert it to an number before, like `var qty3=+$('#totalDiesel').text();`

Comment: updated the html code kindly check it now :)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Kindly add relevant HTML and CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: `<td style="font-size:medium;">Rs.<span  id="totalFish" class="totalFish"></span></td>` and use `var fish = +$('#totalFish').text();`

Comment: @AsadKhan You logic in the code does not make any sense. you try `$('#totalDiesel').text()` but that div contains the text `RS.` how do you expect to add that to a multiplication ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you putting values in your div.
Lets say you have some hidden way of doing so, how are you expecting to add Rs. +Rs. ? Or, would you have Rs. 2 + Rs. 3?
In that case, trim the "Rs. " from input and parse it to Integer for calculation

```
val = parseInt(val.substring(3))
```

after that, all arithmetic operations should work